# renaming file with user input name

Tags: perl, perl-module

I want to rename my temporary file "file3.c" to user input file name.
Using rename or move command from File::copy doesn't rename it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

#input header file
print "Input file1:\n";
$input = <>;
open(FILE1, $input) || die "couldn't open the file!";

open(FILE3, '>>file3.c') || die "couldn't open the file!";
...
#some work on file3.c
...

close(FILE1); 
close(FILE3);

#renaming prepended temporary file name to original file name
rename("file3.c", "$input");
```

OUTPUT
no renaming occurs

How do I rename it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably only need to `chomp` your input to remove the newline:

```
chomp(my $input = <>);
```

And you should always check for an error `$!` when performing file operations:

```
rename($foo, $bar) or die "Cannot rename: $!";
```

Also, you should most often use `or` instead of `||`, since `||` has higher precedence. For example, this is a common beginner mistake, that is rather hard to discover:

```
open my $fh, "<", $file || die $!;  # WRONG!
```

Because logical or `||` has higher precedence than comma `,`, the `die` statement will never happen, unless `$file` happens to be a false value.